# How to get SharePoint tenant site URl using Javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jsom

i will get SharePoint Tenent Site URl using Javascript...

**below My Site URL:-**
https://pp1.sharepoint.com/sites/Test/Poject/

**I have get only Tenent Site URL:-**

https://pp1.sharepoint.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code:

```
var tenantUri = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
//you can replace window.location.protocol with https: as in case of SPO it will always be https 
console.log(tenantUri)
```

This will give you the tenant url irrespective of your path.

Answer (score 1):

code to get root site collection url:

```
string rootSiteCollectionURL = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].Url;
```

// site collection url

```
string SiteCollectionURL = SPContext.Current.Web.Site.Url;
```

**Using JavaScript:**

```
window.location.origin
```